# Build number auto increment from another build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need help in understanding how to increase the build number from another build number,

Example:-

I have Dev, Stage & Prod, branches & build a pipeline

In Stage, I will update the build number format has a 10.0.1$(buildid.buildnumber) it will increase the version number from last build number + 1, & deployed to AppStore / PlayStore

If I do same in Prod pipeline then it will not deploy in AppStore / Play store because the last version number received the Stage was more then current Pipeline number.

Can anyone help me how to increase the Prod number from Stage pipeline?

Comment: Then you should not use multiple build, You should follow the practice of `Build once deploy more` strategy. So that your build artifact will be same through out the environment, where you can change the configuration alone.

Comment: it based on Management requirement, they need in this way,